# why does this correlated subquery return an error in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Here is the query in question :

```
SELECT name, totals1.all_purchases
FROM accounts, 
    (SELECT orders.account_id, SUM(total) AS all_purchases 
    FROM orders 
    GROUP BY orders.account_id) totals1
WHERE accounts.id = totals1.account_id
AND totals1.all_purchases >= 
    ALL (SELECT totals1.all_purchases FROM totals1);
```

The error text returned is the following:

```
ERROR:  relation "totals1" does not exist
LINE 8:     ALL (SELECT totals1.all_purchases FROM totals1);
```

I know I can easily solve this problem using a postgres CTE, and that it would be the better approach. But I want to understand why this code behaves this way, and want someone to point out the flaws in my logic. By the Wikipedia definition of a correlated query:

> a correlated subquery (also known as a synchronized subquery) is a subquery (a query nested inside another query) that uses values from the outer query.

> because the subquery is correlated with a column of the outer query, it must be re-executed for each row of the result.

My logic is, since a correlated subquery is driven by the outer query, it should execute after the outer query. Therefore this inner query should have no problem recognizing the totals1 table.

For example, this code fails as expected, because when the FROM statement is first executed, the subquery that creates totals1 has not yet been executed.

```
SELECT name, totals1.all_purchases
FROM accounts, totals1
WHERE accounts.id = totals1.account_id
AND totals1.all_purchases >= 
ALL(SELECT totals1.all_purchases 
   FROM (SELECT orders.account_id, SUM(total) AS all_purchases 
      FROM orders 
      GROUP BY orders.account_id) totals1;
```

I am also aware of the existence of the LATERAL keyword. I don't think it applies to this situation though, I believe that was meant for correlated subqueries in the outer FROM clause. Case in point I literally used it in every way possible to no avail.

Could this be a possible limitation of PostgreSQL, or is it in the SQL standard altogether ?

PS: here is the schema. You might recognize it from the Udacity's SQL for data analysts course.

[image]

Comment: The query show does not give the error you show.   Rather it gives 'ERROR:  relation "totals1" does not exist'.

Comment: Are you just trying to find the account that's spent the most?

Comment: @jjanes thank you for pointing this it out, just fixed it.

Comment: @dwhitemv yeah, but it's not about what I'm doing it's about why I'm doing it. I want to know why this particular subquery returns the error, not an alternative way to get the same result..

Comment: I don't think there is any profound answer.  It doesn't work that way because that is not the way it works.  The alias assigned to a subquery (yours is uncorrelated, by the way) is just used to qualify column names, not to create a CTE.

Comment: @jjanes "(yours is uncorrelated, by the way)" Lol, i feel so dumb now. Thank you for pointing this out, again. But now I wonder why the second query where I create the totals1 relation inside the ALL statement query fails. Is it not supposed to execute first since its uncorrelated ? So the outer query should recognize it. And if the alias is not supposed to work that way, then why does it work when I use aliases of subqueries in the select statement like this https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/195872/240549 ? I'm sorry i'm asking too many questions, I'm just really confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are allowed to reference the derived table `totals1` in the `WHERE` clause, as you already do but here we are actually referencing a column, not the table as a whole:

```
WHERE accounts.id = totals1.account_id
```

**But** while `totals1` is still visible inside the subquery, it is **not allowed to use it in a `FROM` clause**.

The only tables allowed to use in a `FROM` clause are the tables and views of the database (including temporary ones) and any CTE that is visible in that part of the query.

Some explanation can be found in [Postgres' documentation about **`SELECT`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html),
section `FROM` clause:

> `FROM` Clause
>
> The `FROM` clause specifies one or more source tables for the `SELECT`. ...
> The `FROM` clause can contain the following elements:
>
> **`table_name`**
> The name (optionally schema-qualified) of **an existing table or view**. *<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>* If ...
> **`with_query_name`**
> A `WITH` query is referenced by writing its name, just as though the query's name were a table name. ...
> ...
> *<sup>(other elements omitted)</sup>*

The SQL standards should have more explicit (and hard to read) details.

Comment: Thank you, that does clear things a lot. Do you know of any resources where I can read about such things ? I could not find any in the postgres documentation.

Comment: Added some more info.